# Java compile error in linux: cannot find symbol "javax\mail\session"

Tags: java, linux

While compiling java file in linux. I get the error: **cannot find symbol : "javax\mail\session"**. I am using mail.jar file. which is already included in classpath. But still I get this error. Please help.

Comment: Better provide error stack trace.Also Check for necessary jar. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it javax/mail/session or javax/mail/Session. S is in caps. Are you using any Ide ?

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, on linux the file separator is a *forward* slash (only windows uses the *back* slash).

Where ever you're using `"javax\mail\session"`, try `"javax/mail/session"` instead

Comment: Yeah, when your question and tags say Linux, it's pretty weird to see random backslashes.